# Estoy utilizando JDK 11 Y me entero que ahora es pago?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo un proyecto propio en java 11 en produccion
hace meses y hace unos dias me entere que es pago
que tendria que hacer?
como se enteran ?

Comment: Hola, pero que pasa si lo dejo asi como esta? me daran de baja de la nube mi proyecto o que sucedera?como se enteran?

Answer (score 14):

Creo que esta pregunta debería mantenerse en Stackoverflow, porque podría evitar que más de un desarrollador caiga en un futuro  en una especie de trampa al usar por inercia un software que ha sido entregado de forma gratuita durante años pero que ahora pasa a ser de pago cuando cualquier programa es lanzado a producción. ¿Acaso alguno revisa minuciosamente los términos y condiciones de los programas que instala? Pues cuidado, porque podríamos tener sorpresas muy desagradables a partir de Java 11.

Stephen Colebourne ya lo advertía en septiembre de 2018 en el artículo titulado *[Oracle's Java 11 trap - Use OpenJDK instead!](https://blog.joda.org/2018/09/do-not-fall-into-oracles-java-11-trap.html)*, <sup>es</sup> *La trampa Java 11 de Oracle: ¡use OpenJDK en su lugar!*

Aquí la traducción del artículo referido, para que los programadores en castellano queden prevenidos de no caer en esta trampa y se encuentren con una factura temeraria de Oracle de la noche a la mañana, o algunos meses después de tener un programa en producción:

*Traducción íntegra del artículo:*

---

TL:DR; Java todavía está disponible a un [costo cero](https://blog.joda.org/2018/08/java-is-still-available-at-zero-cost.html), solo necesitas dejar de usar Oracle JDK y comenzar a usar una compilación OpenJDK, como [esta](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot) o [esta](https://jdk.java.net/11/).

## La trampa

[Java 11](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/11/) ha sido [lanzado](https://jdk.java.net/11/). Es una [versión mayor](https://blog.joda.org/2018/09/java-release-chains-features-and-security.html) porque tiene soporte a largo plazo (LTS). Pero Oracle también lo ha configurado para ser una trampa (ya sea de forma deliberada o accidental).

Durante 23 años, los desarrolladores han descargado el JDK de Oracle y lo han usado de forma gratuita. Escribe "JDK" en tu motor de búsqueda favorito, y el enlace superior estará a una página de descarga de Oracle Java SE (deliberadamente no estoy proporcionando un enlace). Pero esa búsqueda y ese enlace ahora es una trampa.

**Oracle JDK, al que te llevan todas las búsquedas web, ahora es comercial, no es gratis.**

La parte clave de los [términos](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/javase-license.html) es la siguiente:

> *Usted no puede: usar los Programas para ningún procesamiento de datos o para fines comerciales, de producción o comerciales internos que no
> sean el desarrollo, prueba, creación de prototipos y demostración de
> su Aplicación;*

La trampa es la siguiente:

1. Descarga Oracle JDK (porque eso es lo que siempre has hecho, y es lo que te  dice la búsqueda web)
2. Úsalo en producción (porque no te diste cuenta de que la licencia cambió)
3. Recibe una llamada telefónica desagradable de los equipos de cumplimiento de licencias de Oracle que exigen mucho dinero

En otras palabras, Oracle puede confiar en la inercia de los desarrolladores de Java para hacer que descarguen la versión incorrecta (comercial) de Java. A menos que leas el texto / advertencias / jerga legal con mucho cuidado, es posible que ni siquiera te des cuenta de que Oracle JDK ahora es comercial, y que, por lo tanto, eres responsable de pagarle a Oracle por usar este JDK particular en producción.

(Actualización, 2018-10-03: ¡Las búsquedas de Java 11 y JDK 11 ahora parecen remitir a las compilaciones de OpenJDK, no a las comerciales!)

¿Es esta trampa un comportamiento malicioso por parte de Oracle? Los lectores tendrán sus propias opiniones. Sugiero tener en cuenta que Oracle invierte grandes cantidades en el desarrollo de Java, por lo que es razonable tener un plan comercial disponible para aquellos que lo deseen. Y proporcionan una alternativa $gratuita completamente válida para uso comercial ...

## La solución

¡La solución es simple!

Use una compilación OpenJDK.

Hay [muchas compilaciones](https://blog.joda.org/2018/09/time-to-look-beyond-oracles-jdk.html) OpenJDK $gratuitas de Java 11, por lo que debes elegir la que mejor se adapte a tus necesidades.

La compilación AdoptOpenJDK es $gratuita, con licencia GPL (con la [excepción de Classpath](http://openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html) segura para uso comercial), y es una buena opción ya que es neutral para el proveedor y tiene la intención de tener más de 4 años de parches de seguridad.

[Descarga Java desde AdoptOpenJDK aquí gratuitamente](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot).

La compilación OpenJDK de Oracle es $gratuita, con licencia GPL (incluyendo la excepción de Classpath y segura para uso comercial), y se proporciona junto con su oferta comercial. Solo tendrá 6 meses de parches de seguridad, después de eso Oracle tiene la intención de [actualizar a Java 12](https://blog.joda.org/2018/09/java-release-chains-features-and-security.html).

[Descarga Java desde Oracle gratuitamente aquí](https://jdk.java.net/11/).

Se esperan más compilaciones Java 11 OpenJDK de [Azul Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/) y su administrador de paquetes estándar.

Puedes ver mis publicaciones sobre [Java de costo cero](https://blog.joda.org/2018/08/java-is-still-available-at-zero-cost.html) y la [amplia variedad de compilaciones OpenJDK](https://blog.joda.org/2018/09/time-to-look-beyond-oracles-jdk.html) para más detalles.

Y para un contrapunto, puedes ver el [gran resumen](http://hirt.se/blog/?p=1036) de Marcus de por qué los cambios subyacentes aquí son realmente buenas noticias.

## Resumen

NO descargues ni uses Oracle JDK a menos que tengas la intención de pagarlo.

Para Java 11, descarga y usa una compilación OpenJDK, desde AdoptOpenJDK, Oracle u otro lugar.

---

Comment: El gran problema que veo es que los desarrolladores NO SON los encargados de poner sistemas en producción. Todas las empresas medianamente serias tienen definidas las tecnologías que usan en producción, cuyas licencias son analizadas por especialistas legales. Así que esto no debe ocurrir. Por otra parte ha habido muchísima desinformación respecto a este tema (no es el caso del artículo compartido) lo único que ahora es de pago es el Oracle JDK y solo si lo usas en producción para fines comerciales. Y las alternativas a este son numerosas.

Comment: @E.Betanzos no se trata siempre de empresas. El OP es un desarrollador independiente y como él mismo plantea, se encontró con este problema a título personal. Yo también estoy desarrollando una App en Java a título personal y quizá me habría ocurrido lo mismo que él al lanzarla a producción.

Comment: Siempre que no la uses con fines comerciales no hay problema. Pero de todos modos hay muchísimas alternativas al Oracle JDK y todas tienen el mismo código.

Comment: bueno me tome la molestia de pasar de jdk 11 oficial al open jdk 11, mi proyecto es 100% informativo y no genera ingresos pero por las dudas, no quiero problemas o sorpresas...

Comment: espero que sea el mismo codigo  ajaja

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/), es OpenSource y de acceso libre:

Con AdoptOpenJDK puedes descargar el paquete de instalación para tu sistema operativo: https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot

AdoptOpenJDK es una iniciativa para proveer de paquetes binarios de OpenJDK para los S.O. principales (Linux, Windows y MacOS)

Comment: y es muy caro adquirir el JDK?

Comment: Desconozco el precio, pero, en mi opinion, si no eres una empresa carece de sentido pagar la licencia, está más enfocada a obtener soporte empresarial por parte de Oracle.